# How to turn on generating documentation based on JSDoc

Tags: visual-studio, jsdoc

I added JSDoc comments above functions in my code:

```
/**
 * Repeat <tt>str</tt> several times.
 * @param {string} str The string to repeat.
 * @param {number} [times=1] How many times to repeat the string.
 * @returns {string}
 */
```

When I hover on invocation of such function or browse through I would like Visual Studio to render documentation above my call like this:

[image]

or this

[image]

Is this is possible?